# WebView With Java Applet

Tags: applet, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a web page with java applet component inside, working properly on Internet Explorer 11 and trying to load same page in Xaml Webview, but it shows that this browser doesn't support applets, so I need to load this web page with applet component inside WebView.

**Note: The Internet Explorer is the default browser on my machine.**

Comment: Are you targeting Windows 10?

Comment: Yes Window 10 is the target OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it shows that this browser doesn't support applets

Please refer to the **Remarks** part of [WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx):

> In apps compiled for Windows 10, WebView uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content. In apps compiled for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, WebView uses Internet Explorer 11 in document mode. It does not support any ActiveX controls or plugins like Microsoft Silverlight or Portable Document Format (PDF) files.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to change the renderer browser to use IE? or even another way to support such embedded components in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: @MoamenNaanou, Nope...check this: [WebView Browser change](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f922683a-1bba-49fe-9fe4-22c956c634b2/uwpwebviewwebview-browser-change?forum=wpdevelop), it's the same question, sorry to say no.